# How to Uncheck ICC profile for image in wpf to remove reddish tint in the image

Tags: c#, wpf, color-profile, color-management

I have developed a WPF Application for saving images by using Canvas.After saving the image iam getting some reddish tint on those saved images.I googled for the solution but i didnt got any solution for that. After long time i came to know that in Adobe Photoshop some IccProfiler is there.If we uncheck that we can retrieve the original image after saving also. Can anybody plz help me regarding this how to get that ICCProfiler to save images in c# and/or WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default colour profile set up on the machine? Have a look in Display Properties->Settings Tab->Advanced->Color Management tab. Is there a colour profile selected in that tab?

I don't know how to change what WPF does with colour profiles, but you could try removing any actively selected colour profiles on the machine (by doing it in the Colour Management tab) to see if it changes the behaviour. I can't think of why you'd end up with a profile on the image unless the machine had one setup, but even then I wouldn't expect it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I have tried that but i didnt got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Everything is WPF is sRGB. If your monitor has a wider gamut you get overly saturated colors. Have a look at the nuget package Mscms.WPF if you want to color-manage your application.